# Javax.swing JFrame hides all components

Tags: java, swing

When I creating standard JFrame with components, I noticed the problem. All components become hidden until, the size of JFrame will not be chosen. I read about this problem, but did not see any way to solve this problem.

```
public class Authorization extends JFrame {
    private String login;
    private String password = "";
public Authorization(String name){
    super (name);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400, 200);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JLabel text1 = new JLabel("text1");
    text1.setFont(new Font(null, Font.PLAIN, 25));
    JLabel text2 = new JLabel("text2");
    text2.setFont(new Font(null,Font.PLAIN,15));
    JLabel text3 = new JLabel("text3");
    text3.setFont(new Font(null,Font.PLAIN,15));
    JLabel text4 = new JLabel("");
    text4.setFont(new Font(null,Font.PLAIN,20));
    JTextField loginField = new JTextField("Login", 10);
    JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(10);
    JButton button = new JButton("button");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() == button){
                login = loginField.getText();
                char[] passwordAr = passwordField.getPassword();
                for (int i = 0; i < passwordAr.length; i++) {
                    password+=passwordAr[i];
                }
                                   if (verification())
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Done");
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong!");
                                        }
            }
        }
    });
    add(text1);
    add(text2);
    add(loginField);
    add(text3);
    add(passwordField);
    add(button);
    add(text4);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain it clearly?

Comment: Call `setVisible(true);` only once all components have been added.

Comment: 1) `setVisible(true);` should be last, directly after `pack();` 2)
    `setSize(400, 200);` leave that out. Don't guess the required size, which is determined by packing the frame. 3) `Authorization` a log-in class is usually better done in a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`